Passport validity while transitting through Bangkok
I'm a Dutch citizen currently staying in Australia. My Dutch passport expires 6th of January 2025 and my return ticket is August 23rd 2024 - flying:
Perth > Bangkok (3 hr layover),
Bangkok > Copenhagen
I just want to make sure I'll be able to enter the plane to Bangkok without any hassle. I have to stay in the terminal and it's all booked on 1 ticket. I'd just like some confirmation and nothing I can find online gives a clear green light.
Thanks in advance!

As a transit passenger on a single ticket, there are no requirements at all on extra passport validity for Thailand.
Actually, I don’t think there are any for Dutch citizens entering Thailand either.
You can check with your actual details using either:

The IATA Travel Centre
Traveldoc


Thank you! Much appreciated:)
